# undefined method `render' for module in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, ruby-on-rails-5

```
module UserCheck
  def self.status(onboarding, params)
    if onboarding && params[:process].present?
      render json: { status: :ok }
    else
      render json: { error: 'You have already finished your onboarding.'  }, status: :not_implemented
    end
  end
end


module MyAccount::User
  class UserController < MyAccountController
    def update
      UserCheck.status(wizard_onboarding, params)
    end
  end
end
```

In the users_controller, I am using the module UserCheck to check the onboarding status and return an error in the else case. But when the else condition runs it doesn’t render json error message but instead returns the `undefined method 'render' for UserCheck:Module`. Could you help me fix this issue?

Comment: Your `UserCheck` doesn't inherit from a `ApplicationController`, and therefore the `render` method (which is a controller method) is not available. It feels to me like you are mixing different contexts here. In the one case the method returns a boolean (that you never use), in the other case, you want to have it a side effect of rendering a JSON response. What do you want to render when the check returns false?

Comment: @spickermann I have updated the question. It was my bad for returning false. How can I use render in the module

Comment: I'd turn `status` into an instance method, include `UserCheck` in the controller, and then simply call `status` in `update`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would pass the controller to that method and call then render on that controller, like this:

```
module UserCheck
  def self.status(onboarding, params, controller)
    if onboarding && params[:process].present?
      controller.render json: { status: :ok }
    else
      controller.render json: { error: 'You have already finished your onboarding.'  }, status: :not_implemented
    end
  end
end


module MyAccount::User
  class UserController < MyAccountController
    def update
      UserCheck.status(wizard_onboarding, params, self)
    end
  end
end
```

Personally, I see no benefit in extracting such simple code from the controller into a module. It makes the controller much harder to understand and to debug. And to understand what the controller is returning, you need to look into a different file.

Comment: spickermann is right about no real value in extracting such a simple method and I'd like to add that if you really want this to be in a different file, I believe you might want to look into the [Concerns](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#using-concerns)